# ListView - Wrong Recycling behavior with ViewHolder Design

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

**Description:**

---

I'm currently implementing a custom ListViewAdapter using the ViewHolder design pattern. The adapter is using a layout with a button that toggles the visibility of a RelativeLayout.

**Problem:**

---

When I click the button and the RelativeLayout is shown, everything seems to work fine until I scroll down. **When I scroll down, I see that other listitems have been effected by the previous button click, so the RelativeLayout is visible on other (wrong) items.** The item that is effected by the button click seems to be the one that is recycled when I scroll down. Please note that everything else works correct, texts etc. are set at the correct position.

**Code:**

---

**CustomListAdapter**

```
public class ItemsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Item> mItems;

public ItemsListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource);
    mContext = context;
    mItems = objects;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    boolean mExpanded;

    public ViewHolder(View view, boolean expanded)
    {
        mView = view;
        mExpanded = expanded;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final Item item = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(v, false);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    if(item != null)
    {
        TextView tvName = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvName.setText(item.getName());

        RelativeLayout rlExpand = (RelativeLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.rl_expand);
        if(holder.mExpanded) {
            rlExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            rlExpand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView tvDescription = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        if(tvDescription != null)
            tvDescription.setText(item.getDescription());

        final ImageButton ibExpand = (ImageButton) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.ib_expand);
        ibExpand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout rlExpand = (RelativeLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.rl_expand);
                if (rlExpand.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    rlExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mExpanded = true;
                }
            }
        });

        ImageButton ibCollapse = (ImageButton) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.ib_collapse);
        ibCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout rlExpand = (RelativeLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.rl_expand);
                ibExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rlExpand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.mExpanded = false;
            }
        });


    }

    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Truism getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Save your View state into your model e.g. isExpanded.

Comment: Sopmething is totally wrong with your code: what's relation between `Item` and `ViewHolder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final Item item = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder(v, false);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    if(item != null)
    {
        TextView tvName = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tvName.setText(item.getName());

        RelativeLayout rlExpand = (RelativeLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.rl_expand);
        if(item.isExpanded) {
            rlExpand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            rlExpand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        TextView tvDescription = (TextView) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        if(tvDescription != null)
            tvDescription.setText(item.getDescription());

        [...]
    }

    return v;
}
```

Change `holder.mExpanded` to `item.isExpanded`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.